# Is there an icon set of cartoonish faces?

Tags: icon

Commercial or free. Something similar like these:

[image]

[Dribble: 3D Face](http://dribbble.com/shots/482481-3d-Face)

---

[image]

[Dribble: Face Proccess](http://dribbble.com/shots/121074-Face-Process)

---

[image]

[Dribble: Face iOS Icon](http://dribbble.com/shots/685520-Face-Replace-iOS-Icon)

I want to use them in a web site for unknown gravatars/avatars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When in doubt, visit [IconFinder.com](http://www.iconfinder.com/) -- [here's one](http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=iconset:faceavatars).
I particularly like the luchadores ...

[image]