# What are good sets of photographic portraits to use in mockups?

Tags: resource-recommendations, photography

I've been using the same set of photographic portraits in my mockups for a long time, and I'm looking for a more extensive set of **square, male and female avatars/photos (portraits)**.

What are good sets to use?

Comment: 'Face Avatars' could mean a lot of quite different types of image, from photographs to abstractions to any number of styles of cartoons including Yahoo style generated cartoons, you'll need to be more specific about what you want and why you're asking here rather than just searching on it, e.g. you could post examples of the ones you currently use.

Comment: I wouldn't use any in a mock up. Once you delve into "faces" you then have to consider gender, ethnicity, and other demographic data. For a "mock up" I'd simply use shapes.

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of avatar sets available online for free. [Here's one example](http://freebiesdesign.com/39-best-psd-avatar-icons-free/#.URJnAvKKwtc). Just use the shapes and re-style them for the needs of your design.

[image: sample avatars]

Most of the sets can be very easily [found through google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=PSD%20Avatar%20Icons%20sets), the real art though is in getting something that fits the layout. Usually you'll find that it's best to obtain an AI or PSD file and change colors / add gradients so that it'd be closer to the design and color pallet you use.

---

If you need photographs of people then SXC.hu got a neat free repository: [Female](http://www.sxc.hu/category/1351?f=s&c=1351) and [male](http://www.sxc.hu/category/1352). Just read the license and respect copyrights!

Comment: I'm looking for photographs of faces – I made my question clearer, sorry about that – and thanks for your help!

Comment: @julien_c If so then here's a solution: [Female](http://www.sxc.hu/category/1351?f=s&c=1351) and [male](http://www.sxc.hu/category/1352) photographs. Browse through the repository and pick what you need.

Comment: @yisela - I already did, right after posting the comment - but instead of throwing it as an additional answer I simply edited this one :) See the bottom part of it, below the horizontal line.

Answer (score 3):

*[I've noted this set before.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/13572/4216) But it's worth repeating.*

## Automatic UI bonus points if your avatars include luchadores.

Who doesn't like extra credit? So what are you waiting for: [**Head to IconFinder to get the set.**](http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=iconset:faceavatars)

[image] [image] [image]
[image] [image] [image]